# How to apply conditions for rows in a tensor where there is boolean values

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have the following tensor:

```
predictions = torch.tensor([[ True, False, False],
                            [False, False,  True],
                            [False,  True,  True],
                            [ True, False, False]])
```

I applied conditions along the axis like below.

```
new_pred= []

if predictions == ([True,False,False]):
       new_pred = torch.Tensor(0)
if predictions == ([False,False,True]):
       new_pred = torch.Tensor(2)
if predictions == ([False,True,True]):
       new_pred = torch.Tensor(2)
```

So I want the final output (new_pred) to be:
**tensor([0, 2, 2, 0])**

But I am getting a blank [] for the new_pred tensor. I think my logic must be flawed since nothing is getting stored in the new_pred. Can someone help me write this logic accurately?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `predictions` is `torch.Tensor` while `([True, False, False])` is a list, first, you have to make sure both sides have the same type.

```py
predictions == torch.tensor([True,False,False])
>>> tensor([[ True, True, True],
            [False, True, False],
            [False, False, False],
            [True, True, True]])
```

Then, you are still comparing a 2d tensor to a 1d tensor, which is ambiguous in an `if` statement, an easy way to fix this would be to write a `for` loop, compare each row of the `predictions` to the conditions and ***append*** the result to the `new_pred` list. Note that you will be comparing two booleans tensors with the size of three, therefore, you have to make sure the result of the comparison is `True` for all of the cells.

```py
predictions = torch.tensor([[ True, False, False],
                            [False, False,  True],
                            [False,  True,  True],
                            [ True, False, False]])

conditions = torch.tensor([[True,False,False], 
                            [False,False,True],
                            [False,True,True]])
new_predict = []
for index in range(predictions.size(0)):
    if (predictions[index] == conditions[0]).all():
        new_predict.append(0)
    # ...
```

Alternatively, you can use slicing to achieve your expected result without any `for` loop.

Comment: Hi Mohammad are you able to show me in an example code how to do the for loop. Sorry I am new to python and not familiar with for loops.

Comment: I added an example; you probably should go read tutorials before moving on to the rest of your work, because it is going to be uphill from here on.

Comment: Hi Mohammad thank you. Yes I will definitely read more tutorials and watch more videos but your example made things very clear.